# how to distribute a web(webapp) with chromium as a single package?

Tags: chromium

My product is a website with some advanced feature that needs chromium.

As a alternative way for the customers do not want to / know how to download the latest chromium, I want to distribute the website with a chromium.

I want to know:

1. how to package a portable chromium with a correct shortcut of the web application.
2. how to compile a own version of chromium that only for my website(web app).

In my own opinion the solutions to the two questions are:

1. use a bat or install script (NSIS etc.) to install the chromium and generate the correct application shortcut.
2. follow the chromium dev instructions to fetch the source code and compile it. And add auto-open-my-app function as well as hiding the tab bar / address bar.

I still want to know better answer.

I remember that there is a project called Prism which is introduced by firefox, is there any equvilent for chromium?

Answer (score 0):

You can dig into several projects that aim to do just that:

- [Atom Shell](https://github.com/atom/atom-shell) (now called electronjs)
- [Node Webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit)
- [Chromium embedded framework](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/)